# What's the percent sign after the address from IPAddress.ToString?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

Calling the `ToString()` method on an `IPAddress` instance that represents an IPv6 address, I get some text with a percent sign after the address. It's [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tostring?view=netcore-2.2). What does it mean?

The return value looks like this: `fe80::1538:3f6c:a202:3af7%3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yours is a `Scoped literal IPv6 address`,

Search by % character in Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address

pasting relevant paragraph here:

> Scoped literal IPv6 addresses
>
> For addresses with other than global scope (as described below), and
>   in particular for link-local addresses, the choice of the network
>   interface for sending a packet may depend on which zone the address
>   belongs to: the same address may be valid in different zones, and be
>   in use by a different host in each of those zones. Even if a single
>   address is not in use in different zones, the address prefixes for
>   addresses in those zones may still be identical, which makes the
>   operating system unable to select an outgoing interface based on the
>   information in the routing table (which is prefix-based).
>
> In order to resolve the ambiguity in textual addresses, a zone index
>   must be appended to the address, the two separated by a percent sign
>   (%).[10] The syntax of zone indices is an implementation-dependent
>   string, although numeric zone indices must be universally supported as
>   well. The link-local address
>
> fe80::1ff:fe23:4567:890a could be expressed by
>
> fe80::1ff:fe23:4567:890a%eth2 or:
>
> fe80::1ff:fe23:4567:890a%3

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that's actually part of the address in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates a non-zero [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Address_scopes) Id. The actual scope Id follows.

Source: [Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,471)